# asp.net membership's user createdate

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am using asp.net membership and roles database. I want to know that that It has a users table. Is there any table in this database where user createdate is saved ? I see LastActivityDate column in aspnet_users table. Please suggest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need aspnet_Membership.CreateDate.

If you're using a standard provider, you can get it like this:

```
        MembershipUser newUser = Membership.GetUser();
        DateTime creationDate = newUser.CreationDate;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's on the aspnet_Membership table.  The column is named CreateDate.